# SQL how to extract date time as value only and combining with other value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 columns from a table as below

```
Time                        ID
2018-06-12 18:24:14:250     116441
```

How can I extract the time as text value only without any of those `-` or `:`? then I want to combine `Time` and `ID` as third column Named as `UID`, add `UID` to the beginning of the combined value.

```
Time                        ID         UID
2018-06-12 18:24:14:250     116441     UID-20180612182414250-116441
```

I tried with `CONTAT(Time, ID) AS UID` but it returned me value as `Jun 12 2018 6:24PM116441`, I need last 3 digits of millisecond after `second` and a `-` in between.

Comment: Either create a _view_, or have a _computed column_. (Values calculated from other columns otherwise tend to degenerate with time.)

Comment: can't use `view`, this will be a scheduled job output to csv file with this extra column `UID`

Comment: Your request is a bit ambigous. What is expected result? a) `UID-20180612182414250-116441`, b) `UID-250-116441` or c) `250-116441`

Comment: @Max the expected result is in the second code-block in the question.

Comment: And another question: what is your goal? just a time-related value as a part of an ID, or a real date representation you can decode back just by reading it? If just an ID, then a datetime is actually a float value.

Comment: The reason I have to create this column is that the table itself contains no `unique value` of each row, I have to create an `unique ID` for each row by using the combination of other rows.

Comment: Why does your table not have something as a primary key? That is the real issue here, not munging these values together.

Comment: @SeanLange The `ID` column is the PK, it indicates the number of the row in that table, I can't just use that value because there is "UNION" between other tables, the `IDs` are all the same starting from `1` in other tales as well. That is the issue. That is why I need to combine "time stamp" up to millisecond   with  `ID` to create a unique identifier in result.

Comment: Why not just add a constant then so you know which table it came from? Then for the other table(s) do the same. Then it would be unique and super simple.

Comment: That is the `UID-` part, in example, I use `UID-` but it will be replaced by `table name`

Answer (score 1):

It's a "bit" long winded, but I'd probably go with:

```
SELECT 'UID-' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(23),[time],126),'T',''),':',''),'.',''),'-','') + '-' +CONVERT(varchar(10),ID)
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2018-06-12T18:24:14.250'),116441))V([time],ID);
```

If you want to use `CONCAT`, then it would be:

```
SELECT CONCAT('UID-',REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(23),[time],126),'T',''),':',''),'.',''),'-',''),'-',ID)
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2018-06-12T18:24:14.250'),116441))V([time],ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select [Time],
       [ID]
       ('UID-' + FORMAT([Time], 'yyyyMMddHHssmmm') + '-' + ID) as UID
  from YourTable
```

Comment: well, this is easy to understand, I got an error `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'UID-20180612181424-' to data type int`

Comment: Well, you asked the UID field to look like `UID-20180612182414250-116441`, which is not an integer value. This is why it fail the conversion. If you need an int value, use `FORMAT([Time], 'yyyyMMddHHssmmm') + ID`, but double check if it fits into int range, you man need 64 bit int.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('UID-',REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'2018-06-12 18:24:14:250',121),'-',''),':',''), ' ', ''),'-','116441') AS UID
```

Replace the string(s) with your Time and ID column.

Comment: Converting the literal `varchar` value `'2018-06-12 18:24:14:250'` to a `varchar(50)` is going to do nothing to change the value.

Comment: Updated the answer with correct conversion of DateTime to Varchar preserving the format as intended in the question.

Answer (score 1):

[T-SQL CONVERT function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
has various flavors to achieve what you looking for along with string concatenation.

```
declare @x datetime = GETDATE()
select @x as x, convert(varchar, @x,112) + replace(convert(varchar, @x,114),':','') as y
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using CONCAT() with DATEPART().

Comment: Shouldn't this have been a comment, instead of an answer?

Comment: No, it's not a critique nor a request for more information, and it's enough of an answer to lead to a solution.  OP already knows CONCAT, and DATEPART is easy enough once you google it.